# OpenGL circle radius issue when drawing square

Tags: opengl, glfw

I have a function that draws a circle.

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    float theta = 2.0f * 3.1415926f * float(i) / float(20);//get the current angle

    float rad_x = ratio*(radius * cosf(theta));//calculate the x component
    float rad_y = radius * sinf(theta);//calculate the y component

    glVertex2f(x + rad_x, y + rad_y);//output vertex

}
glEnd();
```

This works dandy. I save the x, y and radius values in my object.

However when I try and draw a square with the following function call:

```
newSquare(id, red, green, blue, x, (x + radius), y, (y + radius));
```

I get the following image.

[image]

As you see, the square is nearly double as wide (looks more like the diameter). The following code is how I create my square box. As you can see it starts in the center of the circle in which it should. And should stretch out to the edge of the circle.

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(x2, y2);
    glVertex2f(x2, y1);
    glVertex2f(x1, y1);
    glVertex2f(x1, y2);
glEnd();
```

I can't seem to understand why this is!

Comment: Your code looks correct (assuming that `ratio=1`). You probably have set some wrong parameters when constructing the circle. Obviously, both `radius` variables do not match.

Comment: My ratio actually is width/height of the parent window! I will investigate.

Comment: Oh, so you do a manual projection. You should leave that to the projection matrix. This ensures that all objects are in the same coordinate system. E.g. you haven't x-corrected your quad.

Comment: @NicoSchertler ah starting to make more sense everything now haha! You fixed my issue, the ratio was the issue! Post an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: I don't think the scaling alone explains the problem. The circle code only scales in the x-direction, but the sizes are different in the y-direction as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're correcting the x-position for one object, you have to do it for all others as well.

However, if you continue this, you'll get into trouble very soon. In your case, only the width of objects is corrected but not their positions. You can solve all your problems by setting an orthographic projection matrix and you won't ever need to correct positions again. E.g. like so:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //switch to projection matrix
glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //switch back to model view
```

where

```
ratio = windo width / window height
```

This constructs a coordinate system where the top edge has `y=1`, the bottom edge `y=-1` and the left and right sides have `x=-ratio` and `x=ratio`, respectively.